# I am receiving Key Error while iam trying to Calculate the percentage of change from the previous day in a stock dataset

Tags: python, finance, stock

I am writing a function that takes the closing price of a stock and calculates the % of the change from the previous date

```
def daily_return(df):
    df_daily_return = df.copy()
    for i in df.columns[1:]:
        # Loop through each row belonging to the stock
        for j in range(1, len(df)):

            # Calculate the percentage of change from the previous day
            df_daily_return[i][j] = ((df[i][j]- df[i][j-1])/df[i][j-1]) * 100

        # set the value of first row to zero, as previous value is not available
        df_daily_return[i][0] = 0
    return df_daily_return
```

```
stocks_daily_return = daily_return(stocks_df)
stocks_daily_return
```

Now there is problem in the given function is that I'm getting key Error

```
KeyError: 1
```

what am i doing wrong?

Not much as i am Newbie to all of this

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Comment: And post a [mre]